# what is the issue with this code ? Why the Netbeans Keeps on Showing an Error nearby Scanner declaration in code?

Tags: java

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Scanner.*;

class tut5 {

    public static void main(String args[]){


        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); // <-- showing an error 

        System.out.println("Enter the two Numbers:");
        int a=sc.nextInt();

    }

}
```

Comment: What do you think `import java.util.Scanner.*;` does? Why do you think so? What error is Netbeans showing you?

Comment: "*showing an error*" what error? How should people with same problem find your post and its answers if you will not place error message in your question?

Comment: @Pschemo -just wanted to say.I didn't thought to ask a generic question, so now I am deleting this question.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis The questions was why the Scanner showing an error, and it is solved now. Thank you assistance.

Answer (score 1):

This line is the problem:

```
import java.util.Scanner.*;
```

It will import any classes within `Scanner` but not `Scanner` itself.  Remove the ending `.*`:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```